# export gridview to excel with custom value formatting

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, excel, gridview

i have in my content page 4 things:

- a single gridview
- query buttons that execute database views and display the results of the queries inside the view in the gridview
- export to excel button that exports the gridview into excel
- send email with the excel above as an attachment

they work fine, however i noticed a strange problem with the formatting of some of the cells within a column, the column has 2 formats applied to the values, "number" and "general", being "number" the incorrect one.

here are some pics of the first few results to illustrate what i'm saying:

in sql server

[image: sql]

in the content page

[image: content page]

in excel

[image: excel]

notice that in sql server and on the page, the cells are displayed with the correct formatting, which is XXXXX.etc (**general formatting**) but the cells with more numbers get formatted as "number"

i'll post some code bellow:

gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true"></asp:GridView>
```

export to excel button

```
protected void Buttonexcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=dados.xls");
        StringWriter sWriter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sWriter);
        GridView1.RenderControl(hWriter);
        Response.Output.Write(sWriter.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Label1.Text = ex.ToString();
    }

}
```

**is there a way that i can force only "general" formatting for the entire xls?**

Comment: You could try adding a style using Response.Write to convert numbers to string. Look at this link: http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-GridView-to-Excel-in-ASPNet-with-Formatting-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Poormina, thank you for your input, my code is now:

```
protected void Buttonexcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=dados.xls");
        StringWriter sWriter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sWriter);
        GridView1.RenderControl(hWriter);
        string style = @"<style> .textmode {mso-number-format:General} </style>";
        Response.Output.Write(sWriter.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Label1.Text = ex.ToString();
    }

}
```

however the excel formatting remains the same, some cells are formatted as "number" and others as "general", i also tried:

```
string style = @"<style> .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";
```

but the result is the same, another thing that i should point out is that not all records within the ITMREF_0 should be like XXXXX.YYYY.ZZZZZ, i'm gonna post a screenshot bellow:

[image: example]

the 12000073 is correct and excel should display it like that, 22284.01.01 should also be displayed like that in excel

i would appreciate some help

**EDIT :** i figured it out, i just needed to add:

```
string style = @"<style> TD { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";
        Response.Write(style);
```

excel still gives me a warning saying that the number is formatted as text or that it has an apostrophe but that's ok

**EDIT 2:**

as i said in the first post i also have a button that sends an email with an excel file as attachment that has the gridview data in it, i want to do the same thing for this method, format the columns as "general" however i can't figure out how.

here's the send email button code:

```
protected void Buttonmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fn_AttachGrid();
}

public void fn_AttachGrid()
{

    StringWriter sWriter = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sWriter);
    GridView1.RenderControl(hWriter);
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(txtto.Text));
    mail.Subject = "Foi";
    System.Text.Encoding Enc = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
    byte[] mBArray = Enc.GetBytes(sWriter.ToString());
    string style = @"<style> TD { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";
    Response.Write(style);
    System.IO.MemoryStream mAtt = new System.IO.MemoryStream(mBArray, false);
    mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(mAtt, "rotina.xls"));
    mail.Body = "Foi detectado o seguinte problema";
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    mail.From = new MailAddress("email_from", "name displayed");
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
    NetworkCred.UserName = "email_from";
    NetworkCred.Password = "password";
    smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.Port = 587;
    smtp.Send(mail);
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "anything", "alert('Enviado com sucesso.');", true);
}
```

could someone help me?

Comment: i figured it out, i just needed to do this

string style = @"<style> TD { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";
byte[] mBArray = Enc.GetBytes(style + sWriter.ToString());

Comment: in export to excel i am not getting format or color as i am using in gridiview.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me

```
        var grid = new GridView();
        grid.DataSource = candidates;
        grid.DataBind();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=candidates.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        grid.RenderControl(htw);
        string style = @"<style> td { mso-number-format:\@;} </style>";
        Response.Write(style);
        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.End();
```